# Getting dateAndTime as 2016-06-16 08:39:36 in string "dateString"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to convert dateString as "2016-06-16 at 08:39:36"

```
 -(NSString *)getSocialWallPostDateFormat:(NSString *)dateString{ }
```

dateString format is `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Thank you in advance

Comment: describe question plz

Comment: Use for it NSDateFormatter

Comment: I have a method
 -(NSString *)getSocialWallPostDateFormat:(NSString *)dateString{
}
I'm getting "2016-06-16 08:39:36" in dateString.
Now I want this format to convert it as "2016-06-16 at 08:39:36"

Comment: What is your current date format?

Comment: Current date format is " YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Comment: check this doc ... same thing explained here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split into two like this....

```
NSDate *date=[NSDate date]; // Today's date.. You can put here your date..
NSLog(@"Today's date: %@",date);

NSDateFormatter *formatter1=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
formatter1.dateFormat=@"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSLog(@"Date : %@",[formatter1 stringFromDate:date]);

NSDateFormatter *formatter2=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
formatter2.dateFormat=@"HH:mm:ss";
NSLog(@"Time : %@",[formatter2 stringFromDate:date]);

NSString *dateString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ at %@",[formatter1 stringFromDate:date],[formatter2 stringFromDate:date]];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

This will give result you like this...
[image]

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Logic:
Use a `NSDateFormatter` to transform `@"2016-06-16 08:39:36"` into a `NSDate` object.
Change the `dateFormat` to fit the one you want with "at".
Use the `NSDateFormatter` to transform the `NSDate` into the wanted `NSString`.

```
NSString *dateStringInitial = @"2016-06-16 08:39:36";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStringInitial];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a method like:

```
-(NSString * )stringFromDate:(NSDate * )dateToConvert {

    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat=@"yyyy-MM-dd";

    NSDateFormatter * timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    timeFormatter.dateFormat=@"HH:mm:ss";

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ at %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateToConvert], [timeFormatter stringFromDate:dateToConvert]];

    return string;
}
```

You are using the NSDateFormatter to create a) a short date and b) a short time and then creating a string with the "at" in between the two.

**Edit:**

Fixed time and date format as answer was incorrect. Similar to @Sneha answer but with entire method.